# -webkit-text-stroke used on :first-letter

Tags: css

I have noticed that when you:

```
*::first-letter, 
*::first-line {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px red;
}
```

It doesn't work in chrome but does in firefox.
Why is that?

```css
*::first-letter {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px red;
}
*::first-line {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px blue;
}
h3 {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  first letter chrome fail
</h1>

<h2>
  first line <br> chrome fail
</h2>

<h3>
  normal h3 selector with -webkit-text-stroke
</h3>
```

is that a bug?
will anyone care about fixing it in chrome?
is it possible to check anywhere if previous versions of chrome didn't have this bug?

Comment: It's a known issue according to **https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke** (tab "Known issues"). As for the roadmap or plans for future releases, you need to look for something like a Chrome issue tracker, which this site is not.